# Get Column value from DataRow

Tags: c#, .net

I guess my question is different then the others about this.

But is there a way to get the value of a row from DataRow ?
For now I have the following foreach to get schemaInfos:

```
foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows
{
   if (row.Field<String>("ColumnName") != "id")
   {
      TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
      MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.HintAssist.SetHint(textBox, UppercaseFirst(row.Field<String>("ColumnName")));
      textBox.Name = row.Field<String>("ColumnName");
      textBox.Tag = row.Field<Boolean>("AllowDBNull");
      textBox.Text = // Here I want to put the value like row.Field<String>("ColumnValue")
      StackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);
   }
}
```

My Question is, can I get the Value of a Column via this foreach too?
For normal I need to do the following, to get the value:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
   textBox.Text = reader[i].ToString();
}
```

But I think that I can't do this in my DataRow foreach too.
Maybe there is another DataColumn Property to get the value for example `row.Field<String>("ColumnValue")` or smth like that.

I also tried the following, which only gives me the value of the first column but not the others.

```
 int i = 1;

 foreach (DataRow field in schemaTable.Rows)
 {
     if (field.Field<String>("ColumnName") != "id")
     {
         TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
         MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.HintAssist.SetHint(textBox, UppercaseFirst(field.Field<String>("ColumnName")));
         textBox.Name = field.Field<String>("ColumnName");
         textBox.Tag = field.Field<Boolean>("AllowDBNull");

         if (dataReader.Read())
         {
             textBox.Text = dataReader[i].ToString();
         }

         i++;

 StackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);
     }
 }
```

Comment: _"for example row.Field<String>("ColumnValue")"_ yes that's it. Can the question be closed?

Comment: Question is unclear. It seems you have a schema-table which contains only meta informations about the table in the database. If you want the values you should read them with a valid sql and then fill a DataTable via DataAdapter.

Comment: The thing is that there is no ("ColumnValue").
Yea I read the schemaInfo to get ColumnName and AllowDBNull. The ColumnName are TextBoxes with a Label of the ColumnName. Now I want to put the value of the Column in the TextBox.Text Property. That's why I cannot do while(reader.Read()) Edited my question.

Comment: the thing is there is no `ColumnValue` if you just select the schema-table. This DataTable never contains informations about the values in the table but just about the columns. Every row in that table is an information-row about a column and not about the data-rows which contains the values for every column.

Comment: I edited my question again. My DataReader only contains KeyInfo but still gives me the first value of the first column. Not the others but the fact is, that i get the value I want althoug i used `CommandBehaivor.KeyInfo` for my DataReader.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found a way to solve my problem:

```
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
   cmd.Connection = connection;
   cmd.CommandText = sql;
   dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
   schemaTable = dataReader.GetSchemaTable();
   int i = 1;
   while(dataReader.Read())
   {
      foreach(DataRow field in schemaTable.Rows)
      {
         if(field.Field<String>("ColumnName") != "id")
         {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Name = field.Field<String>("ColumnName");
            textBox.Tag = field.Field<Boolean>("AllowDBNull");
            textBox.Text = dataReader[i].ToString();

             StackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);
             i++;
         }
      }
   }
```

first I copied my foreach loop to the using. And tested the Code i edited to my question which is similar with this Code. But the other Code only gave me the value of the first column. Then I tried to remove the `if(dataReader.Read())` which doesn't worked because I need to use `Read()` before.

So i put `while(dataReader.Read())` at the top and placed my foreach loop inside the while loop.

No I have what I want :)